# How to add gdi32.lib from command line

Tags: gcc, linker

I have found an example where gdi32.lib should be linked in some way, but I don't know how to do this from GCC command line. All the examples I've found suggest to do this somewhere in project properties in MS Visual Studio or Eclipse.

**bsod.cpp**:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main() {
    HDC dc = CreateCompatibleDC (NULL);
    SetLayout (dc, LAYOUT_RTL);
    ScaleWindowExtEx (dc, -2147483647 - 1, -1, 1, 1, NULL);
}
```

My GCC compiler is from Ruby Development Kit (seems to be MinGW).

Comment: How interesting... Did I really write this question in 2013?

Answer (score 15):

Just add this to the link command line:

```
-lgdi32
```

So that e.g. your link line will look like

```
gcc -o executable somemain.o -lgdi32
```

Make sure the library is specified *after* anything that needs it.

---

For example, if you have a single C++ source file named `myprog.cpp`, you would run

```
g++ -o myprog myprog.cpp -lgdi32
```

Or seperate the commands

```
g++ -c myprog.cpp
g++ -o myprog myprog.o -lgdi32
```

You can add optimization or debug options to the first two commands. The link command doesn't really need anything else.

Comment: So, I have `myprog.cpp`. What the command line should be? All I did before is `gcc myprog.cpp`

Comment: rubenvb: I did as you suggested, but got: `error: 'SetLayout' was not declared in this scope`. SetLayout is declared in gdi32.

Comment: @Paul that's a compiler error. It cannot possibly have anything to do with the gdi32 library file. Did you forget to include `<windows.h>`?

Comment: @Paul then either your header is broken or something else I can't see in my magic ball is broken. Show your exact code. And show where you got your compiler.

Comment: @@rubenvb: I hope to repair your magic ball with an updated question.

Comment: I know this is unlikely to be answered due to the posts age, but could someone elaborate on how `gdi32.lib` translates to `-lgdi32`? Is this documented somewhere? Would this work with `user32.lib`/`-luser32`.

Comment: @Jimmy Unfortunately, it seems [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) is a bit vague. The [documentation of GNU ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) is more specific, yet incomplete. MinGW(-w64) linkers passed -lbla will look for libbla.a, libbla.dll.a, (lib)bla.dll, I believe in that order. On 32-bit (and 64-bit, but C only) it can link with bla.lib, but I never did and don't know where in the above list that one appears.